# How to represent complex numbers corresponding to a single quantity in a polar plane?

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.6

I have a Python list in which each row contains two columns. The first column contains a real number (**th**) and the second column contains a complex number (**voltage**).

```
0.25  (1.2457255255383563e-09 - 7.827999559008199e-11j)
0.225 (1.2769209019868422e-09 - 1.1957504414521587e-10j)
0.2   (1.3221477572417824e-09 - 1.6359636324117563e-10j)
0.175 (1.382055160135606e-09  - 2.0572240011775488e-10j)
0.125 (1.5471711559849657e-09 - 2.696133396356665e-10j)
0.075 (1.787743723105496e-09  - 2.8204767576743745e-10j)
0.025 (2.0887332185896165e-09 - 2.0611142376588599e-10j)
```

I want to plot these **voltages** on a polar plane, labelled with their corresponding **th** values.

Using the following code, where `data` is the table I have shown above:

```py
def th_polar_plots(data):
    th = []
    vreal = []
    vim = []
    for row in data:
        th.append(row[0])
        voltage = complex(row[1])
        vreal.append(voltage.real)
        vim.append(voltage.imag)
    plt.polar(th, vreal, 'ro-', th, vim, 'bo-')
    plt.show()
```

I am able to generate this:
[image]

Not only is this incorrect, but it also fails to make any sense to me. Because what I need is each voltage vector with a dot/circle on it for the **th** value, since in the future I would need to plot more such **th** vs **voltage** tables in the same plane for comparison.

Edit: I have formatted the spacing and indentation in the table for better readability.

Comment: I can neither see how this is incorrect, nor do I understand what you want instead. Can you explain a bit more which part of the plot do you not like? Maybe note that polar plots are usually used to plot angles, but you have not converted your data to angles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your radius is wrong in the `plt.polar()` call. Try the following in your code,

```
radius = np.sqrt(voltage.real**2 + voltage.imag**2)
plt.polar(th, radius, 'ro-')
```

Comment: Yes, you are right about the radius. Turns out that I can just use the `cmath` library to get the magnitude and phase of the complex number which can then be plotted using the polar plot.